# Do any traditional sources discuss if Zenobia was Jewish?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, maseches-terumos

[Zenobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenobia) was the ruler of the Palmyrene Empire (c. 270 CE). It is conjectured by [some scholars](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/15241-zenobia-septimia) that she was Jewish (likely by conversion). The only explicit reference to her in the Talmud of which I am aware is [yTerumot 8:4(46b)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Terumot.8.4.13?vhe=Mechon-Mamre&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) in which she releases a captive Rabbi, but which does not seem to bear on the issue. I would like to know if any traditional sources discuss Zenobia and comment whether or not she was Jewish.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Wikipedia article you quoted, the answer is no.

The source for this claim in Heinrich Graetz's *History of the Jews* ([volume 2, p. 529](https://archive.org/stream/historyofjews02grae#page/528/mode/2up)):

> A Christian report represents the empress Zenobia as a Jewess, but the Jewish authorities make no mention of this fact.

Seeing as Graetz's history is one of the sources cited for the claim of the *Jewish Encyclopedia*, I doubt that there is any further basis to the conjecture.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is considered traditional, but [Rabbi Tzvi Peretz Chajes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwi_Perez_Chajes) wrote an essay on the Jews of Tadmor, AKA Palmyra, in [Hashiloach vol. 14](https://www.nli.org.il/he/newspapers/?a=is&oid=haschiloah19041201-01&type=staticpdf&submitted=1&e=-------he-20--1--img-txIN%7CtxTI--------------1&g-recaptcha-response=03AGdBq25gDCXfsuxh58TtIjTFidsPuSdGxI64Pf8NUiqc0AD8ExC-yiDxUtM_-Wt3xzmFsa-c3JbI3-WeX9svVukF9anAFYc22wRdCXsy4RTgmsiU9aOayul1GS_oGJHbKmdbIfV8G7N-NYPYUYC6D-s9Zv4m8X-nJxsB90ccO0UV2S1ZyyYJUwoHnNhs0baJwGObLe6WgeiPaBr9EPgibgLE5CNe9SLJ-_ViOi02GvgR5YGggAhy_ZcY9AcL0OZye08q1UM88ndB7dbdJmI0qPBaac5eRRYwwjhuhO7EKBiM-8KIpntWZt13U20jEOYmATSBNI_85H1KNdzPsyp6_X6CHXy1KYUPoLnhULWi62ViQUURvza7rNe2Vx_pH-Xsa_i3-4zbitHPwW8TGjsR1Fz-rDn7A90gOD7a9gxjxzS29jmJUDDYpkY5oK5RW4aT1KciBUQ8DFSItitecmDXBvZvTIJCQ2A5ENluY7eQltcVBwVA-00-5SGludF10bJAyEhaw2AxnGcWlFmsVGQ-gAGo5iZS220xqw), pp. 546-552. On pg. 548, footnote 9, He noted that his grandfather, the [Maharatz Chajes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvi_Hirsch_Chajes), thought that "Tzimtzemai Malketa" ([Shabbat 63a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.63a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) was a scribal error and originally referred to Zenobia, but he, Rabbi Tziv Peretz Chajes, doubts that a scribal error could be so great. He further discusses the supposed Jewishness of Zenobia and doubts the possibility. He thought that at best, she might have rejected idolatrous practices.